# Why this suggestion is only in the email input

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

Hello i have a form with different input fields.

i want to know why only the suggestions ( autocomplete ) of the email input contain  the email of my connection page and password saved by chrome.

i have try to delete the id="email" and the name="email" also the data annotations but suggestions appear also only for this input.

finally i want to disable this suggestion in this input i have tried also with autocomplete attribute but i have the same problem.

Here my code html :

```html
<div class="col-6">
   <label class="col-12 px-2 mdc-text-field">
      @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Email, new { @class = "mdc-text-field__input", @style = "padding-left: 20px;" })
      <span class="mdc-floating-label" style="padding-left: 20px;">Mail</span>
      <div class="mdc-text-field__bottom-line"></div>
   </label>
   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>
```

Here my model :

```
 [Required(ErrorMessage = "L'adresse mail est obligatoire")]
    [RegularExpression("^[a-zA-Z0-9_\\.-]+@([a-zA-Z0-9-]+\\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,100}$", ErrorMessage = "E-mail invalide")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
```

Comment: It sounds like the browser is performing the autocomplete _not the website/JavaScript_

Comment: @phuzi maybe yes

Answer (score 2):

So, here is what I understood from your question.

Your browsers suggests your stored email/password in the fields and want to avoid this.

**Possible solution in a bare minimum code:**

Key is to tell the browser not to suggest anything by turning the autocomplete off.

```
autocomplete="off"
```

You can set it in your form like this,

```
<form method="post" action="blah" autocomplete="off">
...
</form>
```

Or, you can set it directly to your field like this

```
<input type="text" id="lalaLand" name="ryan" autocomplete="off">
```

This should solve your problem. However, if it still doesn't work just give some garbage value in the autocomplete property instead of "off".

```
autocomplete="Katakomb"
```

I wouldn't recommend the last one since its a dirty workaround. Use it only if you run out of options.

**Update 1:**

From your comment I see disabling is not working for you. Try this one to see if it works. (Not able to post this in the comment due to the characters @ )

```
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(
    model => model.Email, 
    new { @class = "mdc-text-field__input", @style = "padding-left: 20px;", autocomplete = "off" } 
)%>
```

**Update 2**

A sample for handling through a custom attribute.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(vm => vm.Blah, new { my_attribute= "myValue" })
```

This will generate a custom attribute in the actual HTML version as below

```
<input my-attribute="myValue" id="Blah" name="Blah" type="text" value="" />
```

Comment: thank you for answer but i wrote in my question i have tried with autocomplete attribute but dosn't work for me and the suggestion of stored email password appear just in the email input for this i want to change this condition for exemple why these suggestion dosn't appear in name input. look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53317764/how-to-enforcing-non-autocompletion-in-email-input

Comment: You are welcome. I have added a small update to my answer. check it. If it doesn't work then may be it may have something to do with your browser settings.

Comment: i did that but also i have the same problem is there a solution to change the structure of the input field to avoid that chrome understand that is an email but in the same time we keep the the name="email" to send information to the server after filling the input fields

Comment: I understand. How about adding a custom property and send it to server?

Comment: okey but how i do that ? can you adding some code to your answer to more understand

Comment: Updated the answer. You can check it out.

Comment: but here i don't have blah in my model i didn't understand you can change data with data of my exemple vm you mean virtual model ?

Comment: Here blah stands for any name you can give for the tag. And you can name the custom attribute as you need, for example my_email_holder which will be transformed into my-email-holder in the HTML. You can access your value from there on. (It's just an example, so I mentioned Blah thinking it is implied that it could be anything you want to put there, apologies anyway!)

Comment: when i write blah or any another name my model have an exception that model dosn't contain definition for this name

Comment: Please take a look at this. Not sure of your output though. This info may help trouble shoot. https://code.i-harness.com/en/q/2675a7

Comment: thank you for your help but it is not a complete answer i still have the same problem i should search for another simple solution